# Django Query for Many to Many Relationship

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many

I have following models.

```
class user(models.Model):
    location = models.ManyToManyField(Locations, blank=True, null=True)

class Locations(models.Model):
    location_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='location Id')
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='location Name')
```

i wanted to get the all locations of a particular user. i wrote this query

```
location_list = user.location.through.objects.values('locations_id', 'locations,').filter(user_id=user_id)
    pprint.pprint(location_list)
```

and it is giving this result;
`[<user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>, <user_location: user_location object>`]

Comment: what's `location.through`?

Comment: With ref to this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306427/django-accessing-raw-many-to-many-created-table-fields`

Comment: What about `user.location.all()`? It'll give you all locations of a particular user.

Comment: It would help for clarity if the names were changed to the proper plurality: `location =` -> `locations =` and `class Locations` -> `class Location`.

Answer (score 1):

The below code should get you the locations for a specific user.

```
location_list = user.location.all()
```

Then in your template you have to iterate over the object so something to this affect

```
    {% for locations in locations_list %}
       {{ locations }}
    {% endfor %}
```