# Auto-fill Django models

Tags: django, django-models

My model contains 3 classes.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(...)

class Attendance(Student, Subject):
    att = model.IntegerField()
```

Now, I want to create an attendance table for each Subject of each Student. Therefore I don't want to fill Subject and Student details for every subject and student again. Please tell me an optimal way of doing this so that at the admin panel I just want to add each subject and student only once.

There may be multiple students studying a subject and there may also be multiple subjects for a student.

(You may tell me another way of doing this instead of inheriting Student and Subject).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ManyToManyField

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    attendance = models.ManyToMany(Subject)    

class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(...)
```

This will be like that

```
id   |    student_id   |  subjects_id
-----------------------------------------
1    |    1            |  10
2    |    4            |  11
3    |    4            |  19
4    |    5            |  10
...
~1000
```

Each Student will have multiple Subjects... while multiple subjects can be from my students

Obs.: Usually i would like to call my ManyToMany relations the name of second table in plural... so subjects

Usage:

```
all_students = Student.objects.all()
all_subjects = Subject.objects.all()
all_subjects_from_student = Student.objects.get(id=1).attendance.all()
```

> How would I mark the attendance of a particular student for a
>   particular subject?

```
particular_student = Student.objects.get(id=1) # When 1 is the student ID
particular_subject_of_student = particular_student.filter(id=1) # When 1 is the subject ID
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

**EDIT** You can do that too without using ManyToMany, if you need any new field at Attendance

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(...)

class Attendance(Student, Subject):
    att = models.IntegerField()
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    ... # You can add more fields if you like
```

Here go one question like yours: [django accessing raw many to many created table fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306427/django-accessing-raw-many-to-many-created-table-fields)

Comment: How would I mark the attendance of a particular student for a particular subject?

Comment: Answer me something... attendance is the relation of 1 or many subjects to each Student?

Comment: Many subjects to each student. As there should be a separate attendance integer field for every student corresponding to every subject.

Comment: This subjects can be used to Many Students? or each Subjects only can be on only one student?